# Blazor - razor page not updating after property from DI Service is changed

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side

Using dotnet 3.1.100-preview2-014569

Ok consider the following example:

Create a new Blazor WebAssemply project from template, then add the following:

`books.razor`

```
@page "/books"
@inject BookService bookService

@if (bookService.isLoaned)
{
    <p><em>Book loaned</em></p>
}
else
{
    <p><em>Book returned</em></p>
}
```

`BookService.cs`

```
public class BookService
    {
        public int BookId { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public bool isLoaned { get; set; }
    }
```

`Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<BookService>();
        }
```

`NavMenu.razor`

```
@inject BookService bookService;
<div class="top-row pl-4 navbar navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">BlazorBlank_PV2</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="books" @onclick="LoanBookClicked">
                <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>Loan Book
            </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="books" @onclick="ReturnBookClicked">
                <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span>Return Book
            </NavLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    private string NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }

    private void LoanBookClicked()
    {
        bookService.isLoaned = true;       
    }
    private void ReturnBookClicked()
    {
        bookService.isLoaned = false;
    }


}
```

What happens:
[image: Not rendering issue]

Expected behavior:
When clicking on the menu item Loan Book the page should show Book Loaned or if I click Return Book it should say Book returned. But this only happens if I click to another page, like Home, and then back again.

How can I force the page to re-render/re-check updated values from BookService even when it's on the same page already?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a new solution in which I implement the INotifyPropertyChanged intereface in the BookService class. Why use this interface ?

- It can be applied to other properties as well
- Notifying clients that a property value has changed is essential part of good services, and this is not limited to only call the StateHasChanged solely for this purpose.
- With the INotifyPropertyChanged intereface implemented, I can pass event data to registered or subscribing objects.

**Important:** Calling a method to update a property value like `bookService.SetLoanedState(false)` is a bad programming and an anti-patterns design. A property can have two accessors, get and set, and they should be used to get a value and to change a value. Methods have different roles...

BookService.cs

---

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;



public class BookService : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool isLoaned;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public int BookId { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }


        public bool IsLoaned
        {
            get
            {
                return this.isLoaned;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value != this.isLoaned)
                {
                    this.isLoaned = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }


        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

### Books.razor

```
@page "/books"
@inject BookService bookService
@using System.ComponentModel


@if (bookService.IsLoaned)
{
    <p><em>Book loaned</em></p>
}
else
{
    <p><em>Book returned</em></p>
}

@code{

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        bookService.PropertyChanged += PropertyHasChanged;
    }
    private void PropertyHasChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
         StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

### NavMenu.razor

```
@code {

    // Code removed for brevity

    private void LoanBookClicked()
    {
        bookService.IsLoaned = true;      
    }
    private void ReturnBookClicked()
    {
        bookService.IsLoaned = false;      
    }
}
```

Hope this works...

Comment: Thanks, Morten_564834... sorry, I've forgotten about the Warning not to place the StateHasChanged method in the OnAfterRender and OnAterRenderAsync methods, the result of which is an endless loop. I'll update my answer to use the  IPropertyChange interface instead. Moral lesson: think before you type...

Comment: np - would love to see other methods using the above example. I've read Chris Sainty's blog before, but wasn't sure it applied to this example and the methods keeps changing, so you never know :)

Comment: Great, I deleted my comment not to confuse people. It works great :) I won't go in the discussion which one is best, they are both viable I believe, but I do like this approach better to avoid methods for setting a property.

Answer (score 4):

books.razor (add a handler for the new onchange event of the book service )

```
@page "/books"
@inject BookService bookService

@if (bookService.isLoaned)
{
    <p><em>Book loaned</em></p>
}
else
{
    <p><em>Book returned</em></p>
}

@code{
 protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        bookService.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
    }
}
```

BookService.cs (add an event action,change the property to readonly, add a setter, trigger event will NotifyStateChanged()

```
public class BookService
    {   
        public event Action OnChange;

        public int BookId { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public bool isLoaned { get; }

        public void SetLoanedState(bool State)
        {
           isLoaned  = State;
           NotifyStateChanged();
        }

        private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();

    }
```

NavMenu.razor (change to use service SetLoanedState()

```
@inject BookService bookService;
<div class="top-row pl-4 navbar navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">BlazorBlank_PV2</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="books" @onclick="LoanBookClicked">
                <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>Loan Book
            </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="books" @onclick="ReturnBookClicked">
                <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span>Return Book
            </NavLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    private string NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }

    private void LoanBookClicked()
    {
        bookService.SetLoanedState(true);       
    }
    private void ReturnBookClicked()
    {
        bookService.SetLoanedState(false);
    }


}
```

for more information look at Chris Sainty's blog post [here](https://chrissainty.com/3-ways-to-communicate-between-components-in-blazor/) it makes this really clear

Comment: Worked as intended. Great :)

Comment: @David Masterson, you should check in the SetLoanedState method whether the value of the isLoaned property is equal to the State parameter, and if it is not, you only then assign the parameter to the property and invoke the OnChange event delegate. Your logic invoke the delegate whenever the user click either the "LoanBookClicked" button or  the "ReturnBookClicked" button. If, for instance, you click the "ReturnBookClicked" button 10 times, immediately after the app is displayed, the isLoaned property being  false by default, and yet, the OnChange delegate is invoked 10 times, which means ->

Comment: that the whole Component page is rerendered 10 times. Incidentally, the isLoaned  property is missing its set accessor...

Comment: Issac, Firstly the question was why the component did not updating its state. I did not add any more code than was needed to explain the answer, Secondly my understanding is that although this code would fire 10 times in your scenario the call to statehaschange would recalculate the DOM tree differences, there would be none, and then do nothing to the page. I know in a perfect world you could test for a change of state be calling NotifyStateChanged but as this code is running in the clients browser an the cost is paid by the user who is click the same button 10 times. why this comment?